# What does thermodynamically consistent mean?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am currently dealing with Cahn-Hilliard-Navier-Stokes equations. Many paper regarding these kind equations talk about the "thermodynamical consistency" of the presented models. For example, in

- S.Aland, A.Voigt, [Benchmark computations of diffuse interface models for two-dimensional bubble dynamics](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/fld.2611), 2011,

the authors present three models and quickly state whether these models are thermodynamically consistent.

Unfortunately, I could not find a decent definition/explanation on what thermodynamically consistent acutally means. Can someone help me out?

Comment: This may be a better fit for physics stackexchange

Comment: See [Thermodynamic equilibrium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermodynamic_equilibrium)